# GOP Reassemble and display order

Tags: image, compression, mpeg

How do you display the following transition in MPEG bit code?

I, P, B, B, P, B, B, B, I, P, B, B, B, P, B, P

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it will be displayed as

I, B, B, P, B, B, B, P, I, B, B, B, P, B, P, P